sudo apt upgrade Deferred
I was trying to do a up date before installing new apps, and received this nifty little issue. Im new to Linux hunted around but...
Any Ideas?
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  cloud-init gnome-shell-extension-appindicator libnss-mymachines
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libudev1 systemd
  systemd-container systemd-dev systemd-oomd systemd-resolved systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd tzdata udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.


When you search this site you will find there is this question many times. The answer to one of them may help you.


Phased updates are software updates that are rolled out in stages, rather than being provided to everyone at the same time. Initially, the update is provided only to a small subset of Ubuntu machines. As the update proves to be stable, it is provided to an ever-increasing number of users until everyone has received it (i.e., when the update is “fully phased”).

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/about-apt-upgrade-and-phased-updates
